# get access to variables inside switch case statement

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

I would like to ask how to get access to data collected inside case 1: statement and display information inside case 2: I don't have access to variables from case 1.
I wonder if it is possible to return the value of these variables and reuse them in the second case for display only.

As a part of project, I used some methods to deliver data to the main method.

```
using System;

namespace Employee_details
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Employees detail info

            int userInput = 0;

            int numberEmployees = 0;
            string[,] table;
            string[,] newTable;
            string name = "";
            string surname = "";
            string phone = "";
            string email = "";
            int row = 0;
            while (userInput != 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Menu");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Create the table");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Show content of the table");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Exit");
                Console.WriteLine("Type the option number");

                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                table = new string[numberEmployees, 4]; // [col, row]
                newTable = tableRestaurant(table);
                switch (userInput)
                {
                    case 1:

                        Console.WriteLine("How many employees does your company have ?: ");
                        numberEmployees = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        table = new string[numberEmployees, 4]; // [col, row]
                        newTable = tableRestaurant(table);

                        for (row = 0; row < numberEmployees; row++)
                        {

                            //Name
                            Console.WriteLine("Write the name for user " + (row + 1));
                            name = Console.ReadLine();
                            string name3 = nameClient(name);
                            table[row, 0] = name3;


                            //Surname
                            Console.WriteLine("Write the surname for user " + (row + 1));
                            surname = Console.ReadLine();
                            string surname3 = surnameClient(surname);
                            table[row, 1] = surname;


                            // Phone Number
                            while (true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Write the phone for user " + (row + 1));
                                phone = Console.ReadLine();
                                string phone3 = phoneClient(phone);
                                if (phone3.Length == 11)
                                {
                                    table[row, 2] = phone3;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid phone number");
                                    continue;
                                }

                            }

                            //Email

                            while (true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Write the email for user " + (row + 1));
                                email = Console.ReadLine();
                                string email3 = emailClient(email);

                                int charPos = email3.IndexOf('@');

                                if (charPos > 0)
                                {
                                    table[row, 3] = email3;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid email format");
                                    continue;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for providing all data. We will keep this data safe.");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        table = new string[numberEmployees, 4]; // [col, row]
                        newTable = tableRestaurant(table);
                        int rowLength = newTable.GetLength(0);
                        int colLength = newTable.GetLength(1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", newTable[i, j]));
                            }
                            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Type any key to continue....");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    default:

                        break;

                }


            }

        }

        public static string nameClient(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }

        public static string surnameClient(string surname)
        {
            return surname;
        }

        public static string emailClient(string email)
        {
            return email;
        }
        public static string phoneClient(string phone)
        {
            return phone;
        }
        public static string[,] tableRestaurant(string[,] table)
        {
            return table;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `I wonder if it is possible to return the value of these variables and reuse them in the second case for display only.` Store them in a field.

Comment: That's because you are re-instantiating table variable in case-2

Comment: Agree this isn't required but I still can't display saved values from case 1. Looks like the variable is empty.

Comment: @Adrian That's probably because you are initiating in the While loop as well.. so when you come second time the values are gone. You need to initialize outside while and nowhere else to keep values.

Comment: Thank you @mjwills. I declared variables in field and I could reuse them later.